# Vuetify, how to style/theme a button to always be "small" and "tile"?

Tags: styles, themes, vuetify.js

How can I change the default appearance of a button, so every time I create a button it will look the same? I understand how to i.e. use the color theme to change the i.e. "primary" color, and how to change the css for i.e. all button background colors.

But how would I go about if I for example want:

All buttons to automatically appear as "small" and "tile" by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own component, e.g. like this one at `src/components/XBtn.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <v-btn
    v-bind="$props"
    small
    tile
    v-on="$listeners"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
  import VBtn from 'vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/'
  export default {
    name: 'XBtn',
    props: VBtn.options.props,
  }
</script>
```

Then elsewhere in your app, you can import it:

```html
<template>
  <v-row>
    <x-btn color="primary">Save</x-btn>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
  import XBtn from '@/components/XBtn'
  export default {
    name: 'SomeOtherComponent',
    components: {
      XBtn,
    },
  }
</script>
```

Or if you want it to be globally available without having to import it each time, you can register it in `src/main.js` like this:

```js
// ... other imports ...
import XBtn from '@/components/XBtn'

Vue.component('x-btn', XBtn)

new Vue({
  // ... main Vue instance config ...
})
```

The cool thing about doing it this way is that the `XBtn` component you derive from `VBtn` will have ALL of the same properties and events. `XBtn` will default to `small` and `tile` but you can still override these by doing something like: `<x-btn large>`. You basically use it the exact same way that you use `VBtn`.